# Detect Firebase Auth Provider for Loged in User

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

How can i check that my user Loged in to my app Using which Auth Provider ? I wanted to detect that did my user loged in to my app using Facebook auth provider or using Email Provider or by using Google auth provider  . I have searched this in Firebase Docs but i couldnt find any proper answer ,

Answer (score 4):

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser.getProviderData().size() > 0) {
            //Prints Out google.com for Google Sign In, prints facebook.com for Facebook
            e("TOM", "Provider: " + firebaseUser.getProviderData().get(firebaseUser.getProviderData().size() - 1).getProviderId());

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always check the list of providers as Malik pointed out. However, as you can have multiple providers linked to the same user, to get the sign in method of the current User with multiple providers, you have to check the ID token. You need to check `firebase.sign_in_provider` claim in the token. That will give you the sign in method used to get the ID token. To get it on the client, you need to getIdToken and then parse the returned JWT with some JWT parser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use method `getIdTokenResult()` of your user object (`firebase.User`) to get `IdTokenResult` object, whose `signInProvider` property you can use to detect signin method of your logged in user.

Answer (score 2):

Reached here for same issue, unable to find the provider that user used to login.
I am working on react-js app using react-firebaseui lib for readymade UI.
After a lil struggle, I simply analysed the "user" object returned by auth and in that we receive an array "providerData".

Without further analysis I decided to use:

```
  const signinProvider = user.providerData[0].providerId;
```

In my case, we use only 2 providers google & password.
I get the user from "onAuthStateChanged" function as below:

```
import { fbAuth } from "./firebase";

fbAuth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      console.log("authStateChanged:=====", user);
      useItFurther(user);
    } else {
      console.log("authStateChanged: no user logged in.");
      cleanUpAuthDetailsIfApplicable();
    }
  });
```

**CAUTION**: I haven't researched why is providerData an array and what more can be there in that array, what could be the sequence when there are more than 1 objects in that array, etc.
In my case, we had to add a condition for email validation based on provider. Like, for a particular domain email address, force user to use a specific provider.

Answer (score 1):

I have been puzzled over this problem and couldnt find an appropriate solution for a long time as well. The solution turns out to be short:

```
String strProvider = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().
         getAccessToken(false).getResult().getSignInProvider();
```

So, `if (strProvider.equals("password"))` then the authentication is by Email + Password,
`if (strProvider.equals("google.com"))` then the authentication is via Google,
`if (strProvider.equals("facebook.com"))` then the authentication is via Facebook.

### Addition

However, with this one-liner you can get an exception wchich can be prevented by adding `OnSuccessListener` like so:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuth.getAccessToken(false).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(GetTokenResult getTokenResult) {
                    strProvider = getTokenResult.getSignInProvider();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternative

> The getProviders() method list is sorted by the most recent provider
>   used to sign in. So the first element in getProviderData() is the
>   method that the user used to sign in.
>
> Also the reason why
>   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderId() returns
>   firebase is because a backing Firebase Account is always created
>   irrespective of how the user signs in. This helps with linking and
>   unlinking of accounts where users may want to attach more than one
>   credential (however your view of the FirebaseUser has not changed).

as mention this [post](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/329).

Comment: Your followup comment (and my own findings) show that this method doesn't seem to work. Can you clarify if you had success?