# In Android Studio, how to check if user logged in anonymously or with email, or google sign in?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have an app. On startup, it is logging in anonymously, automatically. Then you can sign in for real if you want. There is a button, that i want to make useable only for "real logged-in" users. I tried this code but this is true for anonymously signed-in users too:

```
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();     
                if(user != null){
                //can use button
                }else{
                    // "please sign in!"
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see whether the user is anonymously logged in by checking its [`isAnonymous()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#isAnonymous()).

If you want to check for specific non-anonymous providers, you can check the `providerId` in the `providerData` as shown here: [Detect Firebase Auth Provider for Loged in User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46253226/detect-firebase-auth-provider-for-loged-in-user)